# One <div> for many items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2. I got this div class SingleNewsMain applied to many news items

```
<div class="SingleNewsMain">                    
                <div class="NewsMainHeader">
                Some header
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainPublishInfo">
                Some Info
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainShort"> 
                            Some Short Content
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainReadMore"> 
                Some Read More
                    </div>
            </div>  
<div class="SingleNewsMain">                    
                <div class="NewsMainHeader">
                Some header
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainPublishInfo">
                Some Info
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainShort"> 
                            Some Short Content
                    </div>
                <div class="NewsMainReadMore"> 
                Some Read More
                    </div>
            </div>
```

In my .css I got following:

```
.SingleNewsMain{
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 110px;
}
```

But the point is, that it is applied only to the first div class "SingleNewsMain", other divs remain unchanged and dont have padding. Where did I fail?

Answer (score 0):

try CSS1 specification important :

```
.SingleNewsMain{
  padding-right: 25px!important;
  padding-left: 110px!important;
}
```

read:http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score -1):

you are only selecting the parent. you need to select the children as well if you want this to be applied. So like this.

```
.SingleNewsMain, .SingleNewsMain div{
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 110px;
}
```

you should see how to use css selectors for  best practice in your code.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: this is not correct and will not solve the problem. He is trying to apply it to all div's with the class .SingleNewsMain and not all div childs

Comment: oh sorry, I think seeing more nesting would help visualize this bettter